# How to search through directory and copy into database

Tags: sql, postgresql

For a single file, I would use (I'm using PostgreSQL):

```
COPY mytable FROM '/usr/info.csv' NULL '' HEADER CSV;
```

However, now I have a folder with possibly 60-100 files that are in the same format ending in the ext as infoPROCESSED.csv and was wondering if there is a method in postgresql to go through the directory and copy the files into mytable? or would I have to write a script to do this?

Comment: Please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a (hackish) way of loading the csv files:

```
for x in *.ext; do psql -d yourdb -qtAc "copy mytable from '/path/to/files/$x' csv header null ''"; done
```